# $E'=\overline E'$? (the limit points of a set = the limit points of its closure?)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $E'$ be the set of limit points of $E$, and $\overline E \triangleq E'\cup E$ be its closure, in some metric space.  Is it true that $E'=\overline E'$?  That $\overline E' \subset E'$ is shown in [Limit Points of closure of A is subset of limit points of A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631268/limit-points-of-closure-of-a-is-subset-of-limit-points-of-a).  And I think the converse ($E' \subset \overline E'$) is clearly also true.  So it appears that we should have $E'=\overline E'$.  Did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: Yes, your conclusion is correct. The opposite inclusion is trivial: if every nbhd of $x$ hits $E$, then certainly every nbhd of $x$ hits $\operatorname{cl}E$, since $E\subseteq\operatorname{cl}E$.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct since $\overline{E}=E\cup E'$, there is
$$
\overline{E}'=(E\cup E')'=E'\cup (E')'=E'
$$
The last step is because $(E')'\subset E'$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.

$\overline E' \subset E'$ holds because if $x \in \overline E',$ then any neighbourhood of $x,$ say $N_\varepsilon(x)$, has an element of either $E$ (which directly implies $x \in E'$ ) or it has an element of $E'$, say $y$. 
Now since $y$ also has a smaller neighbourhood (which contains an element of $E$) in $N_\varepsilon(x)$ concludes that $x$ is in $E'$. Hence, $\overline E' \subset E'$.

The other side is trivial since the non-empty intersection of any neighbourhood of $x (\in E')$ with $E$ implies non-empty intersection of that neighbourhood with  $\overline E$. Thus, $E' \subset \overline E'$.
Hence, $E' = \overline E'$.